# .htaccess clean url with more than 3 paramenters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am new to .htaccess and I seem to be having some problems getting it to clean up the url for me.

I have

```
site.com?p=article&id=3&read=article title
```

I am able to get the first variable to work ok like `site.com/articles`. but when I try to go further the server is saying it cant find it. I have tried several methods none of which seem to be working.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?p=$1
```

this above is working

I have tried

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)(/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+))?/?$ index.php?p=$1&i=$2
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&i=$2&read=$3
```

the last 2 are not working. help please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's try something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1&id=$2&read=$3 [L]
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. Do you know if having space in the title of the article would affect the way it read is? i.e. &read=blah blah blah ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

%{QUERY_STRING} is what you are looking for.

this is what I use for a similar situation:

```
RewriteRule   ^/(.*)  /index.php?r=/$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. Do you know if having space in the title of the article would affect the way it read is? i.e. &read=blah blah blah ... Thanks

Comment: Spaces will be encoded and show up as %20 in the browser if that's what you're asking, it's a best practice to not use spaces in URLs, I would probably replace them with hyphens if possible. Looking up at the URL in my web browser right now, stackoverflow also replaces spaces with hyphens.

Comment: ah, ok so use something like str_replace in php? and I am assuming your r in the string stands for p in my script right?